# htaccess: direct to php if php is present, if not, direct to directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php file at www.example.com/media.php
I also have a directory of the same name at www.example.com/media/manyotherfiles.php

If I enter my url as www.example.com/media or www.example.com/media/, I want to be directed to the file at www.example.com/media.php, instead of the files inside the work directory.
However, if I enter my url as www.example.com/media/manyotherfiles, I want to be directed to www.example.com/media/manyotherfiles.php. (it's more intuitive as the media.php file links to the pages in the media directory)

How can I do this with my .htaccess file? So far I have this to remove the .php file extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Options -Indexes
```

Also, I am currently working on a beta directory on a local server, so for example, my files would be as such:

```
ip.address.here/beta/index.php
ip.address.here/beta/media.php
ip.address.here/beta/media/manyotherfiles.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to hide `.php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't work - I get a 404 not found error when i try to access any php file now, except for index.php. It says something like "/media/manyotherfiles" not found.

Comment: Can you open `http://domain.com/media/manyotherfiles.php` in browser? Make sure this is rule is before other rules and it is placed in root .htaccess

Comment: Yes I was, but I can't open php files like this: `http://domain.com/page.php`. The file's in root access though.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by **The file's in root access though** so it is not clear why you can't open `http://domain.com/page.php`